# gdb: How to redirect the log-file of shared lib to gdb output

Tags: c++, gdb

I want to debug a shared lib which is called by my program. The shared lib outputs to a separate log file: shared-lib.log. I would like to redirect the lib’s output to gdb (I want to redirect the output to the same terminal where GDB is running). I tried the following:

```
(gdb) run myprogram shared-lib.log>1

(gdb) run myprogram shared-lib.log>/dev/stdout

(gdb) run myprogram /dev/stdout
```

But this doesn't work, also with full path name /var/log/shared-lib.log.

Comment: What does “redirect the lib's output to gdb” mean?  You want to use it as gdb's command line input?  Have you tried making `shared-lib.log` a fifo, and then reading from the fifo with some other tool, such as `cat`, `tee`, or even the shell's redirections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The shared lib outputs to a separate log file: shared-lib.log.

If you have sources for that library, you can modify it to *not* do that. If you don't, you should let its developers know that you didn't appreciate their choice of logging (it's ok to provide a way to redirect library output somewhere, but it's not ok to insist on doing so without letting you decide for yourself).

> I would like to redirect the lib’s output to gdb.

Presumably you want to redirect that output to the same terminal where GDB is running, so you can see what the library output looks like while you are stepping through your program.

You could try this as the first step:

```
rm -f shared-lib.log && ln -s /dev/tty shared-lib.log
```

If the library simply does `open("shared-lib.log", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, ...)` then that should be enough. But it wouldn't work if the library performs `unlink("shared-lib.log")` first.

In that case, not all is lost, but it gets harder. You would want to find out which file descriptor the library is writing to (on Linux, `ls -l /proc/<pid-of-inferior>/fd` should tell you). You would also want to arrange to have an open `fd2` going to `/dev/tty`. Finally, you'll want to call `dup2($fd, $fd2)` to redirect the library output to the terminal. You may also need to `fflush(NULL)` in your program, otherwise the library may fully buffer its debug output (since it thinks that its output is going to a file, and stdio fully-buffers such output by default).

Comment: Thanks, the first step didn't work but it is smart. The second step doesn't work in my case because I don't get a reasonable file descriptor. There are many and I don’t get a link to the lib.
I have the source code. Therefore I have to do the old staff. Thank for you great answer.